# PCHANNEL MOSFET doesn't work in Proteus due to breakdown current problem

Tags: mosfet-driver

When I simulate this H bridge,  I get a bad result:  the break down current increase to 3.59335e+007 A.
What is the problem with it!!!

The motor rotates for just 1 or 2 second then I get this error.
Also, sometimes, when the motor does turn on, the speed of the motor varies quite a bit. It goes fast and then slows down and then goes fast again. What is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your P-channels are flipped the wrong way.